# Why the default padding classes of tailwind css not working after I add a custimization to It?

Tags: tailwind-css

After adding this custom padding class in *tailwind.config.js*

```
  module.exports = {
         theme: {
      padding: {
          yt: '56.25%'
        }
    }
```

I am able to use the class as pb-yt for bottom padding.
However the normal classes for padding which used to work doesn't work now.
Eg : `p-8 p24 px-4 pb-4` are default classes by tailwind which used to work before I added the custom class.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking to extend the config (e.g., add the `p-yt` class but keep existing padding classes).

Luckily, Tailwind has a solution. Instead of doing what you had, move the `padding` object into an `extend` object.

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      padding: {
        yt: '56.25%'
      },
    }
  },
}
```

This tells TailwindCSS to add the `p-yt` utility *and keep existing padding utilities*. When you set the configuration without the `extend` object, you completely overwrite the existing configuration.